# How to handle when C++ crashes and pass the crash details to objective c

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm trying to work out how should I handle when my C++ code crashes and send the needed information to the objective c code.

Basically the application that I'm currently working on has all its core code in C++ so we can use the code for multiple platforms.

We have crash reporting when the objective c code crashes but currently it doesn't grab the crash information if it was the C++ code that crashed it. How do I capture the crash information from C++ so I am able to send this with my crash reports (which we use hockeyapp)?

Edit:
Actually Hockeyapp does catch the crash, what I need is grabbing the log details either from the console or from my C++ log manager (which stores all the messages).

Comment: Can you explain how your crash reporting works? Every "crash report" system I'm familiar with should handle any crash, whether in C++ or Objective-C or C or even assembly code. You're not just capturing Objective-C exceptions, are you?

Comment: Oh yes sorry forgot to add that. We use hockeyapp which seems to only pick up objective C crashes that I know of. We also use TestFight when we do testing in house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by catching signals, getting the stack dump and saving it to a log. The application will read from the log and send it to hockey.

Comment: It would be great is you could post some code with your answer, as to how and where exactly did you catch the signals and got the stack dump, in Objective C or C++? I too am trying to generate C++ crash reports for IOS/Android.

Answer (score 1):

If the exceptions occur deep within a C++-only file, then there's little you can do, but if the application is throwing exceptions in Objective-C++ code, then you can `catch` the exception, then `@throw` an Objective-C exception in response.  You could even just wrap `main` in a `try-catch` block to catch every C++ exception, then rethrow them into Objective-C land.

Comment: Would that be able to handle memory type crashes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  A crash is a crash, an exception is an exception.  You'll never be able to catch 100% of crashes, but you can catch 100% of exceptions if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Yes true. So that isn't going to work. Seems I can use signal to do what I want. But will need to research more into it.

Comment: Actually I was getting confused, I don't need to catch the crash since Hockeyapp does that but I somehow need to read the C++ logs either straight from the console or from my log manager. Maybe if I write my logs to disk and then read them when it crashes hmm...